# Python AWS Lambda Module Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda implemented in Python 3.7 and deployed in a package arranged as below:

```
universe-UIFunctionCelestial-XXXX
|--universe-0-0-1-SNAPSHOT
| |--src
| | |--lambdas
| | | |--__init__.py
| | | |--celestial_persist_function.py
| | |--__init__.py
```

The following image shows this package as deployed in the AWS console:
[image: code portion of Lambda console]

The Lambda is accessible via API Gateway. Its GET method successfully invokes the Lambda, however the Lambda returns the following error:

> Wed Mar 04 09:49:35 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'universe-0-0-1-SNAPSHOT/src/lambdas/celestial_persist_function': No module named 'src'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
>
> Wed Mar 04 09:49:35 UTC 2020 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'universe-0-0-1-SNAPSHOT/src/lambdas/celestial_persist_function': No module named 'src'. Lambda request id: 381990d0-f193-4e49-b0fa-2c6d736552bd
>
> Wed Mar 04 09:49:35 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502

I was under the impression that the Python Lambda execution imports the lambda as a module, so I added `__init__.py` files at each level. Thes might help the lambda import as well as the imports within the lambda like:

```
from src.persistence.persistence_service import PersistenceService
```

Anyway, I have tried a number of different arrangements and file structures. What might I might be doing wrong?

Incidentally, all the code executes locally without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in Python, but looks like you should upload your code with another root folder. Please, try to move ..../src/ to /

P.S. And I recommend to use serverless.com framework to build your lambdas - it's much more easier for start

Comment: as I mentioned, I tried a number of arrangements, changing names and moving directories around was amongst them

Comment: ummm. yep, the serverless framework, I've been there about a year ago. Actually I used CloudFormation, which is AWS's own deployment method, I'd be rather surprised, however, if the choice of deployment framework made any difference to an internal python error.

Comment: The Serverless Framework (serverless.com) and CloudFormation are related but different. I recommend taking a look at the former. Makes deploying serverless applications to AWS much simpler.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon actually, SF working on top of the CloudFormation. Please, check an example here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/examples/hello-world/python/

If you still want to do it by yourself: try to move your functions in / and packages under /lib directory. Python just can't found target namespace under lambdas directory, I suppose

Comment: look, thanks guys about all your touts for SF, but I'd really love a solution to THIS problem please

Comment: I will try the removal of src and use of lib, but it seems pretty odd that the AWS Lambda python interpreter would be making this assumption, I mean they'd actually have to write code for that. Are you sure your not confusing serverless's default setup with python module loading? as I said I have used serverless before, I didn't like it very much, but that, I believe, is a completely different discussion, unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: well, needless to say, changing the names of base directories made no difference whatsoever. Still looking for a solution here. Welcome any suggestions that don't involve advertising the Serverless Framework.

Comment: I'm sorry @ Hannon César and @ Lücks , I never did - I gave up and went with a Java solution - pity really, python is my fist love, but I just couldn't get it working - and unfortunately the only answer to this question was a serverless shill who had no interest in the question i was asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's have been a while since the question was asked but I will answer it anyway - maybe it will help someone else.

I had the same issue - the thing with Lambda is that it runs inside the **src** folder and it does not understand your imports. What you need to have instead is:

```
    from [folder inside src] import [filename]
```

therefore your imports should look like this:

```
    from persistence import persistence_service
```

After this you will be able to invoke *PersistenceService*.